# Add "Open with" to the Context Menu for a particular file, like .js, in windows

Tags: windows-8, windows-registry, context-menu

I want to add a context menu option *only* for `.js` files, so that I can open them with a software (like [atom.exe](https://github.com/atom/atom-shell), or [node.exe](http://nodejs.org/))

Similar to this: [howtogeek.com/add-open-with-notepad-to-the-context-menu-for-all-files](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-open-with-notepad-to-the-context-menu-for-all-files/) **but for** ***particular*** **files** (`.js` in my case) instead of all files.

I tried to do the same thing as described in the above howtogeek link on the registry key `HKCL\.js\shell\...` (instead of on `HKCL\*\shell\...`) but that didn't work.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do it in the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\JSFile\shell` registry key instead of `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.js\shell`. Here `JSFile` is data of default value of the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.js` registry key.

Comment: @JosefZ Hmm didn't work for me. On closer looks, it doesn't even seem to have any other options that I do have on my .js files' context menu (like "open with sublime text"..)

Comment: Which Windows version? This article could help: [How to Add Any Application Shortcut to Windows Explorer’s Context Menu](http://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/).

Comment: @JosefZ I'm on windows 8. Not sure why this isn't working for me. I even changed the existing option of "edit" but the change didn't take place. http://i.imgur.com/pcC70NF.png It seems my JSFile registry key is somehow detached from my .js files' context menu options. And yes, I've even tried restarting the the system.